# Using a scala template variable in Javascript, PLAYFRAMEWORK

Tags: javascript, playframework

I am using playframework and I retrieve data from mysql and assign it to Lists.
I want to assign counts.username to an array in javascript in my `index.scala.html` file. `"@(posts: List[Data], counts: List[UserInfo])`, I am not sure how to do that.

```
@(posts: List[Data], counts: List[UserInfo])
@main("Forum"){
<div class="col-sm-5" style="background-color:cyan;" >
    <h1></h1>
    <script src="@routes.Assets.versioned("javascripts/d3.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script>
  var canvas = d3.select("h1")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", 500)
    .attr("height",500);
    var bars = canvas.selectAll("rect")
                .data(@counts.numberofpost)
                .enter()
                    .append("rect", "black")
                    .attr("width", function(d){return d;})
                    .attr("height", 10)
                    .attr("y", function(d, i){ return i * 100});
    console.log(d3);

</script>
}
```

Comment: Please post your relevant code for review.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to stay away from scala templates and to use ajax calls to load complex data that will be used in other js apis (d3 in your case).

For your case, there is no proper way to do it as you are passing a list of objects. 
For primitive types, you can assign the value to a hidden input and read it from the js code.

Best regards.